# Get fragment instance within PreferencesFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Via a checkbox in my preferences, the view of a fragment must be updated. The preferences are within a PreferenceFragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {...}
```

This fragment is instantiated in an Activity using:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
```

My app has some other fragments, which extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Upon the checkbox change in the preferences, I have to update the view in this fragment:

```
public class OfferingsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          // This view needs to be updated
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offering_tiles, null);
          ...
      }
}
```

My question is: How can I update this view from within the PreferencesFragment? Apparently, I cannot use getFragmentManager to get an instance of OfferingsFragment because OfferingsFragment is a fragment from support library. Is there a way to access OfferingsFragment from within PreferenceFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options based on how your app is setup.  If both fragments are not active at the same time, the Offerings fragment can just read the value from the SharedPreferences when it creates the view.

If both fragments are active and the view needs to be refreshed, you can either create a callback through the parent activity using an interface, [example here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).  Or an easier route is to use an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [Green Robot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)